# Why does BlueShift Aerospace Launch from Maine?

Tags: rocketry

Today there was a new story that BlueShift Aerospace launched the Stardust 1.0 from the [Loring Commerce Centre](https://www.loring.org) in Maine into orbit.

I thought that the launches typically went from as close to the equator as possible, in order to get a push from the Earth's rotation. Why would anybody launch into space form Maine?

c.f. https://www.wmtw.com/article/maine-aerospace-company-launches-worlds-first-biofuel-rocket/35375142#

Comment: I think this is probably best answered at [Space Exploration](https://space.stackexchange.com)

Comment: 5000 feet altitude is hardly "into orbit". I would call that a test flight which could be conducted from anywhere.  Launches from equatorial sites are beneficial if going to low inclination orbits. If going to a polar, the launch latitude does not make much of a difference.

Answer (score 2):

From [Stardust Generation 1 — bluShift Aerospace](https://www.blushiftaerospace.com/stardust-generation-1):

> Stardust 1.0

> Basic testbed launch vehicle for experiments requiring subjection to the vibrations and accelerations of launch and parachute recovery. Ideal for student and budget payloads.

Based upon the mission parameters of the testbed and an altitude of 5000 ft, means they can do it anywhere.  Factor in their mailing address is Maine and it makes perfect sense.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize they were only going up to 5000 ft.

Comment: It was in the link you provided.

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear to me!